# Adding Google Guava to Android project - significantly slows down the build

Tags: java, android, build, guava, dex

After adding Google Guava r09 to our Android project the build time increased significantly, especially the DEX generation phase. I understand that DEX generation takes all our classes + all jars we depend on and translates them to DEX format. Guava is a pretty big jar around 1.1MB

1. Can it be the cause for the build slowdown?
2. Are there anything can be done to speed this up?

P.S. Usually I build from Intellij, but I also tried building with Maven - same results.

Thanks

Alex

Comment: I've noticed this too. Adding Guava makes my build take ~30s instead of ~8s.

Comment: I've separated the classes I use from Guava. That helped reducing build time for me. Unfortunately, unless Guava guys decide to split the library into smaller modules, this is the only way as I see it for speeding up the development build.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For what it's worth, my gut is that this isn't the cause. It's hard to take a long time doing anything with a mere 1.1MB of bytecode; I've never noticed dex taking any significant time. But let's assume it is the issue for sake of argument.

If it matters enough, you could probably slice up the Guava `.jar` to remove whole packages you don't use. It is composed of several pieces that aren't necessarily all inter-related.

I don't think this is going to speed things up, but maybe worth mentioning: if you run the build through Proguard (the optimizer now bundled with the SDK), it can remove unused classes before you get to DEX (and, do a bunch of other great optimization on the byte code). But of course that process probably takes longer itself than dex-ing.

Comment: I've tried to slice the classes I need out, but pretty fast found myself with 40 classes and counting, besides it's ugly :)
The thing with ProGuard is that I haven't found a way to embed it in Intellij build. Thanks.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Proguard, and it's worth even if it takes time (at least in this case)

Comment: @AlexV: Couldn't you run ProGuard once manually to find out what classes are needed? I'd bet it doesn't get tired by counting to 40...

Comment: @maaartinus at the end what I did is extract the functions I use to my own classes. I know this sucks, but even after running Proguard there are too much Guava classes left. I've ended up with ~ 6 classes (Lists, Maps, Iterables, etc).

Comment: @alex ProGuard in Idea: go to File > Project Structure > Modules > YourModule > Android > Compiler tab and check Run ProGuard. Then go to your module directory and run `android update project -p .` to generate the default _proguard-project.txt_. That's it, you have ProGuard optimizing and obfuscating your classes before they get to the DEX compiler. You can tweak what ProGuard does by modifying the _proguard-project.txt_.

Comment: @SnakE That's cool, but I'm pretty sure this feature wasn't there a year ago