# How to create an immutable list in Kotlin that is also an immutable list in Java?

Tags: java, immutability, kotlin, immutablelist

I have a Java/Kotlin interop problem. A Kotlin immutable list is compiled into a normal java.util.ArrayList that is mutable!

Kotlin (library):

```
class A {
  val items: List<Item> = ArrayList()
}
```

Java (consumer):

```
A a = new A();
a.getItems().add(new Item());   // Compiles and runs but I wish to fail or throw
```

How to make my Kotlin class fully immutable from Java perspective too?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kotlin, but the guava Java library has an `ImmutableList` type which you could use to wrap the mutable `ArrayList`.

Comment: unmodifiableList(ArrayList())

Comment: Works. Post it as an answer please.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kotlin and Immutable Collections?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727657/kotlin-and-immutable-collections)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

All non-`Mutable____` collections in Kotlin are **compile time read-only types** by default, but not **immutable**. See the following code snippet:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  // Explanation for ArrayList(listOf()) later down the post
  val list: List<Int> = ArrayList(listOf(1, 2, 3))
  println(list) // [1, 2, 3]

  // Fails at compile time
  // list.add(4)

  // Uh oh! This works at runtime!
  (list as MutableList<Int>).add(4)
  println(list) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

To truly have an immutable list, consider Guava's `Immutable____` collections:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val list: List<Int> = ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3)
  println(list) // [1, 2, 3]

  // Fails at compile time
  // list.add(4)

  // Fails at runtime, as expected
  (list as MutableList<Int>).add(4)
  println(list) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
}
```

Be aware that some of Kotlin's standard runtime function may return collections that are either unmodifiable, not resizable, etc., so all bets are off when you directly cast a read-only collection to a mutable one.

For example, `listOf()` currently (*this may change in the future!*) returns a `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList` around the array of vararg parameters via `Arrays.asList(T...)`. This "list" can be modified, but elements can never be added or removed, as you cannot resize an array. See [`Arrays.asList(T...)` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) for more information.

If you really want a mutable collection from any given collection, consider making a copy using `.toMutableList()`. This will work on any collection:

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  val list: List<Int> = ImmutableList.of(1, 2, 3)

  val copy = list.toMutableList()
  copy.add(4)

  println(copy) // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  println(list) // [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Comment: Guava has to be avoided on Android. `Collections.unmodifiableList()` is the safest and simplest solution.

Comment: @WindRider [Guava can be used with Android just fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978699/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-google-guava-library-for-android-development) but ProGuard is recommended

Answer (score 1):

There is `ImmutableList.copyOf(list)` that returns an `ImmutableList`.
This is Kotlin API, and you won't be able to use it in Java.

Another option is `Collections.unmodifiableList` from `java.util`, when used in Kotlin, it returned a mutable list type, but just like in Java, you will get an exception if you attempt to modify it.

Comment: Does this still exist in the stdlib?

Comment: [kotlinx.collections.immutable](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable) provides immutable collections (i.e. methods like `List.toImmutableList()`)