# kotlin1.3 multiplatform - Convert arraylist to an immutable lsit

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a kotlin Multiplatform library  which can later convert into java and javascript using  **IDEA 2019.3, kotlin 1.3**

I have an array list with me and I want to convert it to a immutable list

```
val clean:List<String> = ArrayList<String>()
```

I could not see an option to convert clean to a immutable list.
From [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable), I can see that kotlin has immutable list implementation but I could not see this in kotlin 1.3 multiplatform project.

Am I missing something obvious ? I could see a similar [[old question][2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564534/how-to-create-an-immutable-list-in-kotlin-that-is-also-an-immutable-list-in-java)  but according to [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.collections.immutable), it seems it should be available. Please help

Answer (score 1):

Use Collections to converts an array list to Immutable list, Example:

Mutable Array list:

```
val clean:List<String> = ArrayList<String>()
```

Converts to Immutable list:

```
val immutableList = Collections.unmodifiableList(clean)
```

Comment: Collections is not available to be in the multiplatform kotlin project

Comment: Please refer this link for multi platform sample projects https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multiplatform.html

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, `listOf(...)` creates an immutable list, as stated in the [documentation of the latest API](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html).

That's why you can just write

```
val clean:List<String> = ArrayList<String>()
val immutableClean = listOf(clean.toImmutableList())
```

where `immutableClean` is a read only list.

Comment: Won't listOf( clean)  produce a List<List<String>>? In the end I  tried something like listOf( *clean.toTypedArray());

Comment: @nantitv Yes, that's possible... I just payed attention to the return type being mutable or not ;-)