# Kotlin: Assert Immutability

Tags: kotlin, reflection, collections, immutability

I have class that internally maintains a mutable list, and I want to provide an immutable view on this list. Currently I'm using the following:

```
/**The list that actually stores which element is at which position*/
private val list: MutableList<T> = ArrayList()

/**Immutable view of [list] to the outside.*/
val listView: List<T> get() = list.toList()
```

First question: Can this be done easier

Second question: How can I test that *listView* is actually immutable. I guess reflections are necessary?

Comment: That's not an immutable view. It's a read-only view. Important distinction. The contents can be changing by whoever has access to the backing MutableList.

Answer (score 0):

If you only needed the *compile-time* type to be immutable, you could simply upcast your list:

```
val listView: List<T> get() = list
```

(Though if you checked and downcast that to `MutableList`, you could make changes — and those would affect the original list.)

However, if you want full immutability, that's tricky.  I don't think there are any general-purpose truly immutable lists in the Kotlin stdlib.

Although `List` and `MutableList` look like two different types, in Kotlin/JVM they both compile down to the same type in the bytecode, which is mutable.  And even in Kotlin, while `Iterable.toList()` does return a new list, the current implementation* actually gives a `MutableList` that's been upcast to `List`.  (Though mutating it wouldn't change the original list.)

Some third-party libraries provide truly immutable collections, though; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564534/how-to-create-an-immutable-list-in-kotlin-that-is-also-an-immutable-list-in-java).

And to check whether a `List` is mutable, you could use a simple type check:

```
if (listView is MutableList)
    // …
```

No need to use reflection explicitly.  (A type check like that [is considered](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/106363/314543) to be implicit reflection.)

<sup>(* That can change, of course.  It's usually a mistake to read too much into the current code, if it's not backed up by the documentation.)</sup>