# How to import Guava into Android applications

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, guava

What is the proper way to import Guava into an Android project?  Every time I try to use it I get a `NoClassDefFoundError`.

This is what I'm doing to generate the crash.  I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7.

1. Create an new project `File > New > New Project`, target `API 26.0`, using the `Empty Activity` template.
2. Add to `app/build.gradle` in the `dependencies` section

   ```
   implementation "com.google.guava:guava:20.0"
   ```
3. Add this to the onCreate method in `MainActivity.java`

   ```
   ImmutableList<String> foo = ImmutableList.of("A", "B", "C");
   Log.d("MainActivity", foo.get(0));
   ```
4. Run the App and open up Logcat to see this exception:

   ```
   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   Process: com.letsdoit.guavaissue, PID: 14366
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/collect/ImmutableList;
       at com.letsdoit.guavaissue.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.letsdoit.guavaissue-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
       at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
       at com.letsdoit.guavaissue.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
   ```

I'm almost certain it has to do with Gauva being large and not playing well with multidex, but am not sure what to do about it.  These are some of the note worthy things I've tried to no avail:

1. Enabling multidex and specifying ImmutableList in the [multiDexKeepFile](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html).
2. Disabling instant run.
3. Pulled the APKs from the device and verified the Guava classes are in the APKs.
4. Following the recommendations in this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14978699/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-google-guava-library-for-android-development).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use guava version `22.0-android` and up.  Make sure to use the `-android` flavor, otherwise you'll run into the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

**Explanation**

I learned after posting the question how to manually clean the project and uninstall apks from the emulator.  It turns out that version `20.0` actually does work, but I had tried version `21.0` right before then and failed to clean.

The non`-android` flavors of guava as of version `21.0` are using Java 8.  The android flavors and versions before `21.0` use Java 7.  This is described in these [release notes](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release22) for version 22.0.

I tested these flavors and versions:

- `20.0 (Java 7)` - works
- `21.0 (Java 8)` - doesn't work
- `22.0 (Java 8)` - doesn't work
- `22.0-android (Java 7)` - works

When using version `21.0` or `22.0` (no `-android`) the `ImmutableList` class is getting referenced but not compiled into the dex files (since it's in italics).  This was causing the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

[APK with dangling references to ImmutableList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY6mT.png)

As the android [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer.html#filter_the_dex_file_tree_view) explain

> In the tree view, italicized nodes are references that do not have a
>   definition in the selected DEX file.

It further explains that

> A DEX file can reference methods and fields that are defined in a
>   different a file.  For example System.out.println() is a reference to
>   the println() method in the Android framework.

But in this case, there is no other file that these methods and class definition should end up in.  It's just failing to add them.

Contrast that to using `20.0` or `22.0-android`, where the ImmutableList class actually gets compiled in.

[APK with ImmutableList defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0EMc.png)

And the app starts up as expected.

Comment: Adding just use `guava version 22.0-android` is not helpful to anyone who is unfamilar with guava.