# App Crashes when using guava Predicate with Java 8 on API 22 or below

Tags: java, android, java-8, guava

I am updating an Old Android project to new one but I am facing an issue on API 22 devices and below.

I've enabled Java 8 in app level `build.gradle` file and there was some code written using guava for filtering out a list which is crashing on my app for API level 22 or below devices.

Below is the function which i created to test the issue and this is also crashing just like the original one right after printing `Initializing predicate` in the `logcat`:

```
import com.google.common.base.Predicate;
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

...

private void testCrashFunction() {

    Log.d("log", "Initializing predicate");
    Predicate<String> predicate = new Predicate<String>() {
        @Override
        public boolean apply(@NullableDecl String input) {
            return input.startsWith("A") || input.startsWith("J");
        }
    };

    Log.d("log", "Created predicate");

    List<String> names = Lists.newArrayList("John", "Jane", "Adam", "Tom");

    Log.d("log", "Filtering List...");
    List<String> filteredList = Lists.newArrayList(Collections2.filter(names, predicate));
    Log.d("log", "Filtered List");
}
```

I am calling this function in my Main Activity.

Below is the crash log:

```
04-30 15:03:28.364 11555-11555/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 11555
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.myapp.MainActivity$e
    at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.F(MyApplication:440)
    at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MyApplication:95)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I also tried by using stream instead of using guava but still no use.

Below is the code i used for stream

```
private void testCrashFunction() {
    List<String> names = Lists.newArrayList("John", "Jane", "Adam", "Tom");
    List<String> filteredList = names.stream().filter(input -> input.startsWith("A") || input.startsWith("J")).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Below is the error i am getting:

```
04-30 15:23:41.476 11818-11818/com.example.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.myapp, PID: 11818
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method stream()Ljava/util/stream/Stream; in class Ljava/util/List; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.List' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
    at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.F(MyApplication:456)
    at com.example.myapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MyApplication:96)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

What could be the issue for guava to crash after enabling Java 8. It was working fine before but is now crashing after i updated my project to java8 and androidx(I don't think this could be the issue).

Please let me know in case you need any other details.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Make sure you are using android version of guava instead of jre. 
otherwise you'll run into the NoClassDefFoundError.
Source - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48333035/how-to-import-guava-into-android-applications

Comment: Yes man, that was the issue. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Okay. I Figured out what is the issue thanks to @AmniX.

I believe its better to put it here as someone might end up wasting hours like me for this issue.

In the project i was working on, guava jre was used instead of guava android

So just make sure if that is the case with you.
Just replace jre with android like below

```
   // don't use jre version in android
   api 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-jre'

   // replace jre with android
   api 'com.google.guava:guava:29.0-android'
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48378440/7071039

Comment: Thanks for this answer, sadly it took me a while to find it and a lot of wasted hours trying to replace most guava code to something usable!